# References for learning Angular2 drag and drop?

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular

Can any one tell me are there any good references for learning Angular2 drag and drop?

Comment: Questions about external references are discourages. I don't think there is much out there about it. Angular is still HTML and JS therefore it shouldn't be too hard to implement. If you run into a concrete problem just create a new question (this one will the probably be a good fit).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any references. But if your drag'n'drop solution is HTML5 based, maybe you can make use of HostListener decorator from '@angular/core' to hack your drag and drop exchange logic:

HostListeners provide you ways to implement conventional listeners for element events like onmousedown, onkeyup, ondrop, ondragstart.

You can add something like this on your drop area component:

```
@HostListener('drop', ['$event']) 
onDrop(event: any) {
    //do something             
}
```

And you can add something like this on your draggable component:

```
@HostListener('dragstart', ['$event']) 
onDrag(event: any) {
    //do something
}
```

The rest is think of some logic to identifiy what's being dragged/dropped and change the drag area component model.

Here's some functional code I've made inspired by W3Schools topic on drag'n'drop (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp):

```
import { Component, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

// The draggable component
@Component({
    selector: 'dragme',
    template: `
        <div draggable="true">
            Drag {{name}}!
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
        [draggable] {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-drag: element;
            -webkit-user-drag: element;
            background-color: #AAA; 
            border: 1px solid black; 
            padding: 24px;
            margin: 12px;
        }
    `]
})
export class DragMe {

    @Input()
    name:string = "";

    @HostListener('dragstart', ['$event'])
    onDrag(event:any){        
        event.dataTransfer.setData("name",this.name);
    }
}

// The drop area component
@Component({
    selector: 'drop',
    template: `
        <div class="drop">
            Drop over me!
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let i of items">{{i}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
        .drop{
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 24px;
        }
    `]
})
export class DropOverMe {

    items:string[] = [];

    @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
    onDragover(event:any){
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
    onDrop(event:any){
        event.preventDefault();        
        var name = event.dataTransfer.getData("name");                        
        this.items.push(name);
    }
}

// The functional example
@Component({
    selector: "drag-example",
    template: `
        <dragme name="Bob"></dragme>
        <dragme name="Alice"></dragme>
        <dragme name="Carl"></dragme>

        <drop></drop>
    `

})
export class DragExample{

}
```

Full code at: https://github.com/rafaelodon/angular2-html5-dragndrop-example

Answer (score -1):

The `angular2-grid` plugin gives grid-based directives for angular2. Maybe it can help in your case!

[This](https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid) is the github repo and you can find a working example [there](http://bmorton.co.uk/angular/)